# Splitting hash url to fill text fields in form

Tags: javascript, forms, url, hash

I have a javascript function for splitting the url for parameters and then setting the values of text fields with those parameters found.  It works perfect... once I refresh the page.  How can I get it to fill the text fields when the page loads?

```
$(function(){   
    var urlParams = {};
    (window.onload = function () {
        var match,
            pl     = /\+/g,
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        urlParams = {};
        while((match = search.exec(query)) !== null)
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
    window.onload=function(){
        var nm= urlParams['name'];
        var pn= urlParams['phone'];
        var em= urlParams['email'];
        document.getElementById('txtName').value=nm;
        document.getElementById('txtPhone').value=pn;
        document.getElementById('txtEmail').value=em;
    }
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is too much window.onload. jQuery's $(function(){}) will be fired when DOM will be ready, and this should be enough for your case. However I tried to reproduce your issue, but the function works for me. Try to remove window.onloads and tell me if it help. Maybe prepare some jsFiddle will be good too.

```
$(function(){
    var urlParams = {};
    (function () {
        var match,
            pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while((match = search.exec(query)) !== null)
        urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();

    var nm= urlParams['name'];
    var pn= urlParams['phone'];
    var em= urlParams['email'];
    document.getElementById('txtName').innerText=nm;
    document.getElementById('txtPhone').innerText=pn;
    document.getElementById('txtEmail').innerText=em;

})
```

Comment: Same result, I'm gonna play with the code on the previous page and see if there's an issue with the code prior to clicking on the link to the form.

Comment: I figured it out, it was definitely the form code from the previous page.  I was passing it wrong, I was initially using <a href="urlherewithhashvalues"> and switched it to javascript with an on click function window.location.href.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it anyways, I still appreciate it!  Can I give points for that?